# Can't find mistake in Pipe

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i got the following Problem with a Pipe in Typescript. I would like to filter an Array with an element which results from another filter Operation with an other Array. I tried to write a Pipe to solve this Problem, but it doesn't work and i don't know why.

Here is the Code of the pipe:

```
@Pipe({
name: 'FilterABC',
pure: false}) export class FilterABC implements PipeTransform {

transform(impacts: any[], secObjec: string, secObjects: any[]): any {

    let x: string = (secObjects.filter((item) => item.secObj === secObjec))[0].toString();

    return impacts.filter((item) => item.securtyObjective.toString() === x);
}}
```

And here is the HTML-Code:

```
<select #imValue class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let impact of impacts | FilterABC:secObj.value:secObjs;">{{impact.securtyObjective.id}}</option>
        </select>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: The select Field is empty.

Comment: you have 3 arguments in `transform` but only using 2 in html. Suggest setting breakpoint or calling debugger in transform and walk through it

Comment: When you use a pipe for filtering, the Array what should be filtered is not an Argument in html

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to return the results from arrow functions inside array filter methods.

Try this updated pipe definition -

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'FilterABC',
    pure: false
}) 
export class FilterABC implements PipeTransform {

    transform(impacts: any[], secObjec: string, secObjects: any[]): any {

        let x: string = (secObjects.filter((item) => { return item.secObj === secObjec; }))[0].toString();

        return impacts.filter((item) => { return item.securtyObjective.toString() === x; });
    }
}
```

I hope this helps :)